# How to enable recently viewed products in product details page?

Tags: magento-1.9, catalog

In magento 1.9.2.4, in the product details page, I want to display 'Recently viewed products' in place of description. How to do that? How to call the `product_viewed.phtml` into the place where description section is residing now as below:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For replacing Description with Recently View products replace this code from `catalog.xml`

```
<block type="catalog/product_view_description" name="product.description" as="description" template="catalog/product/view/description.phtml">
    <action method="addToParentGroup"><group>detailed_info</group></action>
    <action method="setTitle" translate="value"><value>Description</value></action>
</block>
```

TO :

```
<block type="reports/product_viewed" name="product.description" as="description" template="reports/product_viewed.phtml">
    <action method="addToParentGroup"><group>detailed_info</group></action>
    <action method="setTitle" translate="value"><value>Description</value></action>
</block>
```

**For Adding NEW TAB for Recently View products, Replace**

```
<block type="catalog/product_view_description" name="product.description" as="description" template="catalog/product/view/description.phtml">
    <action method="addToParentGroup"><group>detailed_info</group></action>
    <action method="setTitle" translate="value"><value>Description</value></action>
</block>
```

WITH:

```
<block type="catalog/product_view_description" name="product.description" as="description" template="catalog/product/view/description.phtml">
    <action method="addToParentGroup"><group>detailed_info</group></action>
    <action method="setTitle" translate="value"><value>Description</value></action>
</block>
<block type="reports/product_viewed" name="product.recentview" as="recentview" template="reports/product_viewed.phtml">
    <action method="addToParentGroup"><group>detailed_info</group></action>
    <action method="setTitle" translate="value"><value>Recently View</value></action>
</block>
```

Comment: When I change the value field it is changing. But phtml file is not changing

Comment: not getting , ??

Comment: I replaced the code with yours. But the recently viewd products are not getting displayed.

Comment: plz, clear cache and visit one or more VISIBLE product

Answer (score 0):

Just add below **code after Description** block in **catalog.xml** files

```
<block type="reports/product_viewed" name="Your_attribute_name" as="reportsproductviewed" template="reports/product_viewed.phtml">
    <action method="addToParentGroup"><group>detailed_info</group></action>
    <action method="setTitle" translate="value"><value>Your tab name</value></action>
 </block>
```

Comment: no changes are happening